# Category whose objects are sets of objects of a different category

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

I'm looking for a reference of the following definition that simple google search did not produce.

Let $C$ be a small locally-small category and let $D\subset P(ob(C))$ be a set. We can turn $D$ to a category with the following data for a morphism:
A morphism $k:d\rightarrow d'$ is a collection of morphisms indexed by $d$:
$\{k_c:c\rightarrow c'_c \}_{c\in d}$ such that $c'_c\in d'$ for all $c\in d$

Is there a name for this category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the same thing, if $D$ is the whole powerset, as the fibered category over Set induced by $C$, which is the category of families of objects and functions between them in $C$. This comes with a nice functor, namely, a fibration, to Set, and can be constructed for an arbitrary locally small category if you allow only small families of objects.

Comment: Thanks! I see that in the nlab page of a Grothendieck fibration, it gives this as an example and calles that category $Fam(C)$